# List displayed wrong on firefox and internet explorer but not on chrome

Tags: html, css, browser, styling

I'm having an issue with a header on my website.
Even tho its displayed properly on chrome, I can't make it to work on firefox and IE.

```
<div id="exlinks" style="margin-top:-82px; ">
<ul id="strl" style="position:relative;" >
<li > <a href="/ueber-uns/" style="padding-right:3px;">Über ServerService</a></li>|
<li> <a href="/kontakt/" style="padding-right:3px;">Kontakt</a></li>|
<li> <a href="/support/" style="padding-right:3px;">Kundensupport</a></li>|
<li> <a href="/sitemap/" style="padding-right:3px;">Sitemap</a></li>|
<li> <a href="/hilfe"style="padding-right:3px;">Hilfe</a></li>|

</ul>
</div>
```

This is the list, displayed on the top.

here is the css:

```
#exlinks
{

padding-bottom:5px;
} 

#strl
{
text-align:center;
font-size:13px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top:20px;
}




#strl li
{

display:inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 8px;
margin-left:0px;
padding-left:8px;



}
#strl li a{
display:inline;
color:#262626;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: color 0.16s ease-in;
-moz-transition: color 0.16s ease-in;
-ms-transition: color 0.16s ease-in;
-o-transition: color 0.16s ease-in;
 transition: color 0.16s ease-in;

 }

 #strl li a:hover
 {

 color:#0489b6;

 }
```

Chrome:
[URL=http://s203.photobucket.com/user/Corbinlock/media/chrome.png.html][IMG]http://i203.photobucket.com/albums/aa4/Corbinlock/chrome.png[/IMG][/URL]
Firefox and IE:
[URL=http://s203.photobucket.com/user/Corbinlock/media/firefox.png.html][IMG]http://i203.photobucket.com/albums/aa4/Corbinlock/firefox.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: Please remove `margin-top: -82px;` from this line `<div id="exlinks" style="margin-top:-82px; ">` And it will be visible in all the mordern browsers. Also the CSS property is not proper. You've mentioned `strlist` as ID. And you've used `#strl`.

Comment: seems like your #strl in the css dont match the ID in your html. if you could fix it and maybe throw it into a jsfiddle or something else, it will be a bit easier to see the problem and help you

Comment: And your image links in the buttom dont work, we cant see the images.

Comment: Thank you will try it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JS fiddle. I corrected the HTML and Css code:

HTML:

```
<div id="exlinks" >
<ul id="strlist" style="position:relative;" >
<li > <a href="/ueber-uns/" style="padding-right:3px;">Über ServerService</a></li>|
<li> <a href="/kontakt/" style="padding-right:3px;">Kontakt</a></li>|
<li> <a href="/support/" style="padding-right:3px;">Kundensupport</a></li>|
<li> <a href="/sitemap/" style="padding-right:3px;">Sitemap</a></li>|
<li> <a href="/hilfe"style="padding-right:3px;">Hilfe</a></li>|
<li style="padding-right:3px;">Gebührenfrei: <b>0800 111 7000</b> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#exlinks
{

padding-bottom:5px;
} 

#strlist
{
text-align:center;
font-size:13px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top:20px;
}




#strlist li
{
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 8px;
margin-left:0px;
padding-left:8px;



}
#strlist li a{
display:inline;
color:#262626;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: color 0.16s ease-in;
-moz-transition: color 0.16s ease-in;
-ms-transition: color 0.16s ease-in;
-o-transition: color 0.16s ease-in;
 transition: color 0.16s ease-in;

 }

 #strlist li a:hover
 {

 color:#0489b6;

 }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wwqHk/2/)